# URL rewrite/redirect through FTP-access in ASP4.0 / IIS8.0?

Tags: .htaccess, asp.net-mvc-4, mod-rewrite, ftp

I am to redirect some URLs from an old site to a new site on a different domain name. Normally I would do this editing/uploading a .htaccess file on Apache servers. Piece of cake.

Now, I've been given FTP-access to the old server.
However, its a ASP4.0 / IIS8.0 server and I cannot use the .htaccess-method it seems.

My questions therefore: is there a solution to this through **only** FTP-access? Should I upload/edit a specific file? I have never worked with ASP-servers.

Help is much appreciated, thanks.